# Is there a WebActivatorEx equivalent for Windows Services?

Tags: c#, windows-services, webactivator

I want to be able to utilise a C# assembly which can be easily be initialised  in a decoupled manner to set up some (AutoMapper) configuration at start-up. [WebActivator](https://github.com/davidebbo/WebActivator) allows me to do this.

But I also want to be able to utilise this assembly in a Windows Service Host environment which I want to be completely decoupled also. Is there something equivalent to WebActivatorEx that I can use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the absence of a response to this question (probably because it was badly worded and a bit questionable in its approach) I came back to it today and decided to look again.

As I want to be able to host an MEF enabled plugin I had used WebActivator to get it working in MVC.

On the WebActivator page I noticed the following comment at the bottom of the page under the heading **Support for invoking the start methods outside of ASP.NET**

> if you are using some 'WebActivated' NuGet packages from a different type of apps (say a Console app), it could make sense to have add calls to Run() and RunShutdownMethods() at the beginning and end of your app

In my case the WebActivator.ActivationManager.RunPreStartMethods() would provide what I wanted. This approach (although it feels a bit hacky!) would allow me to run the same plugin (without Web dependencies) from a Windows Service.